# Use of logical AND/OR without conditional/branching

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, boolean-logic, short-circuiting

I am trying to write a function that counts some bit flags while avoiding the use of branching or conditionals:

```
uint8_t count_descriptors(uint8_t n)
{
    return 
    ((n & 2)   && !(n & 1))   +
    ((n & 4)   && !(n & 1))   +
    ((n & 8)   && !(n & 1))   +
    ((n & 16)  && !(n & 1))   +
    ((n & 32)  && 1       )   +
    ((n & 64)  || (n & 128))  ;
}
```

Bit zero is not directly counted, but bits 1-4 are only considered if bit 0 is not set, bit 5 is considered unconditionally, bit 6-7 can only counted once.

However, I understand that the boolean && and || use short-circuit evaluation. This means that their use creates a conditional branch, as you would see in such examples: `if( ptr != nullptr && ptr->predicate())` that guarantees code in the second sub-expression is not executed if the result is short-circuit evaluated from the first sub-expression.

The first part of the question: do I need to do anything? Since these are purely arithmetic operations with no side-effects, will the compiler create conditional branches?

Second part: I understand that bitwise boolean operators do not short-circuit evaluate, but the only problem the bits do not line up. The result of masking the nth bit is either 2^n or zero.

What is the best way to make an expression such as (n & 16) evaluate to 1 or 0?

Comment: Ok. So you're really smart and can do clever things with bits. No one else is going to have a clue what your version is actually supposed to be doing (even if you do comment it, the comment will eventually drift away from the code. They always do.) Why not just write it in a clear and maintainable way to start with?

Comment: Apple LLVM 8.1.0 optimizes the routine to code without any branches (for its default macOS target). However, this is not behavior you can rely on. Different compilers will do different things, and even one compiler may do different things in different circumstances. Mostly, you should write clear code and avoid things that obscure what is going on for either people or the compiler.

Comment: answer for second part: `(n & x) << x` will get you a 0 or 1 for `x = 2^k`

Comment: To extend Eric's sentiment: Modern compilers with optimizations enabled are more than smart enough to generate optimal code for such functions. Avoiding branches is also not necessarily faster. I'd just write this function so that a human can understand it without too much effort, and let the compiler work its magic.

Answer (score 1):

I assume with "bit 6-7 can only counted once" you mean only one of them is being counted

In this case something like this should work

```
uint8_t count_descriptors(uint8_t n)
{
    uint8_t retVar;

    retVar = (n&1)*(n&2 >> 1) + 
             (n&1)*(n&4 >> 2) + 
             (n&1)*(n&8 >> 3) +
             (n&1)*(n&16 >> 4) + 
             (n&32 >> 5) + 
             (int)((n&64 >> 6) + (n&128 >> 7) >= 1)

    return retVar;

}
```

Comment: I'm curious, for such operations as these, `(n&1)*(n&4 >> 2)` where the boolean comparison is only being performed on the 0th bit, why multipliation is preferable to bitwise AND?

Comment: @stands2reason It probably would do the same with `&` instead of `*` but i find it easier to read this way.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the best way to make an expression such as (n & 16) evaluate
>   to 1 or 0?

By shifting it right the required number of bits:  either `(n>>4)&1` or `(n&16)>>4`.

I'd probably use a lookup table, either for all 256 values, or at least for the group of 4.

```
nbits[16]={0,1,1,2,1,2,2,3,1,2,2,3,2,3,3,4};
//count bits 1..4 iff bit 0 is 0, bit 5 always, and bit 6 or 7
return (!(n&1) * nbits[(n>>1)&0xF]) + ((n>>5)&1) + (((n>>6)|(n>>7))&1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the cleanest way to convert (n & 16) into 0 or 1 is to just use `int(bool(n & 16))`. The cast to `int` can be dropped if you are using them in an arithmetic expression (like `bool(n & 2) + bool(n & 4)`).
For your function of counting bits set I would recommend using the popcount intrinsic function, available as [__builtin_popcount](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.1/gcc/Other-Builtins.html#Other-Builtins) on gcc and [__popcnt](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385231.aspx) on MSVC. Below is my understanding of the function you described, changed to use popcount.

```
f(n & 1)
{
  //clear out first 4 bits and anything > 255
  n &= 0xF0;
}
else
{
  //clear out anything > 255 and bottom bit is already clear
  n &= 0xFF;
}

return __builtin_popcount(n); //intrinsic function to count the set bits in a number
```

This doesn't quite match the function you wrote, but hopefully from here you get the idea.